# Problem creating Repl.it function boolean for javascript

Tags: javascript, function, boolean, sandbox, replit

Been trying to find answers to learn up my amateur understanding of javascript. Working inside Repl.it for my class and as a beginner, so I feel like there's a lot that's been stripped down to extreme basics, which doesn't help when I go looking for a solution.

ORIGINAL PROBLEM IS TO DO THIS:

```
// orderPizza takes in a boolean
// if it is true return the string 'cheese pizza'
// if not, return the string 'pepperoni pizza'
// Example: orderPizza(true) returns 'cheese pizza'

function orderPizza(vegetarian) {

}
```

---

I attempted MANY, MANY different combinations trying to figure out what I was doing incorrectly, and at this point, I just don't recognize what's what anymore. Here's one of my latest guesses:

```
function (vegetarian) {
let orderPizza = vegetarian;
    if (orderPizza = vegetarian) {
        return ("Cheese Pizza!");
    } else {
        return ("Pepperoni Pizza!");
}
};
let newOrder = vegetarian
console.log(newOrder)
```

---

Comes up with an error. Any solutions out there community?

Comment: Correction: I had this to begin with: 

    function orderPizza (vegetarian) {
    let orderPizza = vegetarian;
        if (orderPizza = vegetarian) {
            return ("Cheese Pizza!");
        } else {
        return ("Pepperoni Pizza!");
    }
    };
    let newOrder = vegetarian
    console.log(newOrder)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error with your code is simply your use of the equals sign = instead of the the logical operator == (equal to)

https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_comparisons.asp

If you rewrite your code as below it will run:

```
function (vegetarian) {
    // this is you set orderPizza is vegetarian
    let orderPizza = vegetarian;
    // Comparison operators is '==' or '===' not '='. '=' is Assignment Operators
    if (orderPizza == vegetarian) {
        return ("Cheese Pizza!");
    } else {
        return ("Pepperoni Pizza!");
    }
};
// this is you set orderPizza is vegetarian not call function
// you can call function with name and parameter
// example: let newOrder = orderPizza(true)
let newOrder = vegetarian
console.log(newOrder)
```

In terms of the question and a good answer for it:

```
function orderPizza (vegetarian){
    if (vegetarian == true){
        return 'cheese pizza'
    }
    return 'pepperoni pizza'
}

order1 = orderPizza(true)
order2 = orderPizza(false)

console.log(order1)
// will log 'cheese pizza'
console.log(order2)
// will log 'pepperoni pizza'
```

note: you don't actually need to use else because the code will only reach

```
return 'pepperoni pizza'
```

if the if expression doesn't find the variable to equal true. A function can only return once. You can think of return as the 'answer' to the function.

you could write

```
if (vegetarian == true) {
```

or

```
if (vegetarian) {
```

because the if expression will evaluate the contents of the brackets. If vegetarian is 'truthy' (https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_booleans.asp) then you don't need to compare it to 'true'.

However in a strict equality sense the comparison will confirm it's value is true as opposed to another truthy value like a string.

Comment: Thank you so much: this response was so helpful and informative. You're helping to make me a more concise coder by exemplifying how little is needed to make the function run. The comparison operator is now officially drilled into my brain, haha. Super grateful, @Happy Machine!

Comment: Feel free to hit me up with any future questions..  glad to help!

Answer (score 1):

Wellcome to Javascript.
But I think you need begin learn js again with [w3school js tutorial](https://www.w3schools.com/js/). It easy to learn.

ORIGINAL PROBLEM IS TO DO THIS:

```
// orderPizza takes in a boolean
// if it is true return the string 'cheese pizza'
// if not, return the string 'pepperoni pizza'
// Example: orderPizza(true) returns 'cheese pizza'

function orderPizza(vegetarian) {
     // check vegetarian is true
     if(vegetarian){
         return 'cheese pizza';
     }else{
         return 'pepperoni pizza';
     }
}

// when you call orderPizza(true). In your function parameter is true
console.log(orderPizza(true));

// when you call orderPizza(true). In your function parameter is false
console.log(orderPizza(false));
```

Your latest guesses is is so error:

```
// your function not have name (function name is name you call function)
// example : function orderPizza(vegetarian). orderPizza is function name. vegetarian is parameter you send to in function 
function (vegetarian) {
    // this is you set orderPizza is vegetarian
    let orderPizza = vegetarian;
    // Comparison operators is '==' or '===' not '='. '=' is Assignment Operators
    if (orderPizza = vegetarian) {
        return ("Cheese Pizza!");
    } else {
        return ("Pepperoni Pizza!");
    }
};
// this is you set orderPizza is vegetarian not call function
// you can call function with name and parameter
// example: let newOrder = orderPizza(true)
let newOrder = vegetarian
console.log(newOrder)
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you, I got it! It was the comparison operators I was using wrong indeed. These are beginning to fill in major blanks for my learning curve. Super appreciate it!